# Setting Unix (CentOS) enviroment var in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell, centos, environment-variables

I want to set an environment var in .bash_profile that will contain a path. When I log in I just want to type cd $var instead of have to type out the entire, lengthy path. I've forgotten how to do this, it's been a while since I've worked in shells..

Answer (score 0):

Edit and then enter in terminal:

`echo "export var=/your/path" >>~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

Then you can use `cd $var` .